# Changing Page Title Dynamically in AngularJS using ngRoute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, title

Though I've managed to change the page title based on different routes, I got stuck when variables come into the picture.

```
<title ng-bind="title"></title>
```

**Angular Portion**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'igTruncate']);

 app.config([ '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$sceDelegateProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $sceDelegateProvider){

 $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    controller: 'BaseController',
    templateUrl: 'views/base.html',
    title: 'Welcome to the Website'
  })
  .when('/about', {
    controller: 'AboutController',
    templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
    title: 'About Me'
  });

}]);

// change Page Title based on the routers
app.run(['$location', '$rootScope', function($location, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
        $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
    });

}]);
```

This works perfectly fine. But since, I'm creating a blog, each blog page should have different title.

My single blog route looks like this

```
 .when('/blog/post/:url', {
        controller: 'PostController',
        templateUrl: 'views/post.html',
        title:  'Blog'
      })
```

I want to get the `url param` from the route and concat it into my title.
For example if the route is like `/blog/post/How-to-change-title-in-angularjs`, then I want to get the url portion and add it to my title so it looks like, *How-to-change-title-in-angularjs | Blog*

Is it possible?

Comment: set the rootscope title in your service or controller request that retrieves the data

Comment: @charlietfl I have but it's showing error. Can you just give an example code?

Comment: show what you tried and what is error?

Answer (score -2):

You may check below from angular documentation:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

You could pass the title from back end.
If there is no back end, it may be simpler to store it in controller's scope